# What is the probability a Quadrilateral formed from a circle has an area of over half the circle

Tags: geometry, geometric-probability

The question is :

Pick 4 random points along the circumference of a unit circle, 1 in each quadrant labeled a, b, c, and d respective to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and 4th quadrants. Connect these points to form a convex quadrilateral. What % of the time is the area of this quadrilateral greater than or equal to half the area of the initial unit circle.

[image]

Ive gotten to the point of a inequality that's seems basically unsolvable to me at least which is:

$$\left|\frac{2ab\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}-b\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}-a\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}+2bd\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}-d\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}-b\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}+2dc\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}-c\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}-d\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}+2ac\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}-c\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}-a\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}}{4\sqrt{2a^{2}-2a+1}\sqrt{2b^{2}-2b+1}\sqrt{2d^{2}-2d+1}\sqrt{2c^{2}-2c+1}}\right| > 0$$

This equation was reached by first drawing a circle

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

Then drawing a diamond around said circle

$$|x|+|y|=1$$

then picking points a, b, c and d along the edges of the diamond. Projecting these points towards the origin and finding the point where these projections hit the circle give us a point on the circumference without any trig (this is because the trig equation is even more nasty). then using the shoelace formula to calculate area we can set the area bounded by the 4 intersections to be greater than pi/2 giving us this thing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Connected : [area of random **triangles**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/304970/88984)

Comment: Taking uniformly distributed random points on what you call "the diamond" doesn't generate a *uniform* distribution on the unit circle.

Comment: Are you aware of the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4715783/305862) asked yesterday by someone else ? Is it an online math contest ?